# WebForm project in Visual Studio Debug mode only show IIS default page

Tags: .net, webforms, iis-express

I am working on an ancient WEbForm project. 
When Press F5, on the former developer's computer, it will automatically compile and open a browser showing project-specific homepage. But I copied the entire codebase to a new development environment, I only "setup" IIS by checking the box in Features of Window, installed MSVS and SSMS. when I press F5, the output indicated " Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
" only a default IIS page show up, worse, I press Ctrl+shift+W on any pages, it only showed the same IIS default page, instead of showing each page content in browser.

It errored out the following HTTP400 message when I specify port number such as `localhost:<port>`, which I found out in the Debug Option Tag in MSVS.

```
Bad Request - Invalid Hostname

HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.
```

I have no idea where to start the debugging, please guide me through.

I would like to provide any necessary information to help you help me!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: which version of VS and .NET are we talking about? Normally you wouldn't need to install IIS if you run the project with F5 from within a VS. Please also check in the web project properties, in the 'Web' tab, if the URL you're providing in your browser is the same as in "Project Url" and what is selected in the 'Start Action' section.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up the application in IIS. Go to IIS Manager and in "Connections" window, right click on your computer name and "Add Website". Fill the "Add Website" form. "Physical path" refers to the folder your site is in. Then you should be able to right click on the new website added and in "Manage Website", click on browse to see the site in default browser. This is the starting point and you will need to configure more later on. Read more [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/323972/how-to-set-up-your-first-iis-web-site).